# Java filenotfoundexception asking until file is found

Tags: java, file, exception

I have to write a program that supports extensions. I have a problem with FileNotFound Exception. Program asks about the name of the file. My task is to write an special information when there is no file like given, and ask again until user will write an existing file name. I know how to write an special information that there is no file, but I don't know how to ask again about the name of the file (I only know that it must be done using readNP method).
Here is the code:

```
import.java.io.*;
import java.util.* ;

class Reading{
   static BufferedReader sysin =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

   String readNP() throws IOException{
   //  ask about file name
      System.out.print("file name ");
      String filename;
      filename = sysin.readLine() ;
      return filename.trim();
```

}

```
  void read(ArrayList<Double> a) throws IOException{
  // reading from file
    int nr=1 ;                  
    String name = readNP();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    a.add(new Double(line));
        nr++;
    }
    br.close() ;
  }
}

class Exceptions{
  static void average(ArrayList<Double> a){
      double s=0.0d;
      for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) 
      s+=a.get(i).doubleValue();
      System.out.println("average from numbers in table: "+s/a.size());
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
      ArrayList<Double> a = new ArrayList<Double>();
      Reading r = new Reading();
      try{
      r.read(a);
      average(a);
      } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          System.out.println("File not found");
      }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add test for existence of file name (and for that it's not the name of the directory) into your `readNP()` function:

```
String readNP() throws IOException{
//  ask about file name
    for (;;) {
        System.out.print("file name ");
        String filename;
        filename = sysin.readLine();
        File f = new File(filename);
        if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) return filename.trim();
        System.out.println("file absent");  //message if the there is no file with this name
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3491139: OK, great!

Comment: But actually this method doesn't support FileNotFoundExcpetion. I tried to give something like else { throw new FileNotFoundException(); } after if , but it is done only once not in a loop.

Comment: @user3491139: But I thought you don't really want to throw exception because that would make repeatedly asking for the correct filename impossible.